# horizontal line not full width on ipad / tablet

Tags: ipad, mobile

a simple horizontal line set at 100% width is getting cut off on the rightside when viewed on ipad, iphone or tablet. PC-based browser no issue.  in the header i have set:

**meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"**

sample page here:  http://www.33degrees.ca/line/

any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: It worked OK on my iPhone... in both horizontal and vertical mode I see a line right across the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try a CSS Reset at the beginning of your site style sheet like the following:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: thx brian - i tried your suggestion but in portrait mode the horizontal line still gets cut off on the right. i was able to see this on both my andrioid tablet and using www.ipadpeek.com